# Stop printing php error messages to browser

Tags: php, linux, netbeans, error-handling, apache

I'm using PHP 5.3, CentOS 6.2, httpd 2.2.15, NetBeans 7.0.1 (running remotely via ftp).

I want to stop printing error messages to the browser, it's enough that it prints to the error_log of httpd.

I thought by doing try/catch I would decide on my own how to handle the error but it still prints to both error_log and browser.

```
function smic_gettext($phrase){

        try{
            $tr_text = $this->language_array[$phrase];

        } catch(Exception $e){
            error_log("Couldn't find any entry in the translation file for ".$phrase.". ".$e);
            return $phrase;

        }

        return $tr_text;
    }
```

How should I configure in order to stop this behaviour?

I have tried setting display_errors=Off and display_errors=0 in php.ini. No difference (I did restart httpd).

Comment: **production environments** should have PHP errors/notices disabled in the `php.ini` file, and only logging to log files

Comment: Side note: Errors in PHP are not exceptions (like in Java for example) but there is a way to convert them to exceptions and handle accordingly. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
display_errors = Off
```

in php.ini will let you keep your syslog errors, but write nothing to the browser.

Comment: I would like to do this for all scripts so configuring php.ini seems to be the best way. I did try display_error=Off and display_error=0, restarting httpd but no difference.

Comment: You tried "display_error", but the keyword is "display_errors"

Comment: Sorry about that, it wast just a typo in my comment, I used display_errors.

Comment: Have you checked, that there is no other occurrence of "display_errors" in the file?

Comment: This was extremely embarrassing... There was duplicate entries of display_errors. Guess it's time for a break. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 13):

You need to change the php.ini setting [`display_errors`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) to `off` or `0`. You can either do this in your actual php.ini, with a .htaccess file, or by calling this at the start of the script:

```
ini_set('display_errors', '0');
```

Answer (score 8):

Try adding the following to the top of your script:

```
ini_set('display_errors',0);
```

This should set the error reporting to none and override the servers php.ini settings (which sometimes ignore your error_reporting(0)  )

Comment: setting error_reporting to 0 will also cause no errors to be logged. I wouldn't advise this in a production environment.  Setting `ini_set('display_errors',0);` should be enough.

Comment: Mchl and klennepette, thanks for the assist.  Nicsoft, they are right, just ini_set('display_errors',0); should do the job.

Answer (score 7):

Wheter or not PHP errors are sent to the browser is determined by the php.ini setting: `display_errors`. Set it to `Off` to avoid it being output. This file is usually located under `/etc/php.ini` or `/etc/php5/php.ini`

Comment: @DaveRandom OP mentioned he is on CentOS and on CentOS this is usually the path.

Comment: I would like to do this for all scripts so configuring php.ini seems to be the best way. I did try display_error=Off and display_error=0, restarting httpd but no difference.

Comment: It should be display_errors (plural), not error. If that's just a typo and display_errors is set to Off, make sure that there is no "overruling" display_errors in your script (e.g. with the ini_set method suggested by others) and there is nothing like `php_flag display_errors Off` in your .htaccess file (if you have one).

Comment: I actually used plural, it was just in my comment I made it singular (can't update it anymore). I am not using any .htaccess file.

Answer (score 2):

If error appears only in one line it is possible to prevent error display with adding sign @ to start of that line.

@YOUR_CUSTOM_COMMAND

Example:

```
@file_get_contents('custom_file.txt');
```

Answer (score 1):

See `display_errors` directive

http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php

Comment: I would like to do this for all scripts so configuring php.ini seems to be the best way. I did try display_errors=Off and display_errors=0, restarting httpd but no difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide errors and warnings, you can also set an error_handler.

See http://php.net/manual/function.set-error-handler.php

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, while `display_errors = off` is the correct config-file line as others have said, on DreamHost (nd possibly other installations), it goes in

`$HOME/.php/phprc`

rather than php.ini (which might also work, but DreamHost -- and, again, possibly others -- supports phprc).